# Removing Year Decimals from x-axis in Pandas Histogram

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I am trying to plot the histogram of my data by year; however, the x-axis 'Year' is shown in decimal format (i.e. (2020.0, 2020.25 ...) not integer format.

Histogram

[image: 1]

I extracted the year from the date string using

`df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['INCI_DATE']).year`

then plotted using pandas hist command

`hist = df.Year.hist(bins=3, figsize=(10,10))`

I tried converting the 'Year' column to int, but get the same results.
`df.Year = df.Year.astype(int)`

How can I get have the years in integer format only?

Comment: What is the data format in `df['INCI_DATE']`? Is it only year - 2020, 2021...? Or is it a full data - 2020/01/26?

Comment: @Redox It is in the following format: 2022/09/21; INCI_DATE, dtype: object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see just the years, don't try change it to year only format. Leave it as datetime and plot it. Matplotlib can show it in the format you need. You can use `set_major_locator()` and `set_major_formatter()` for this. Below is the updated code... Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
## You can update INCI_DATE as datetime, or create a new column... 
df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['INCI_DATE'])#.year
hist = df.Year.hist(bins=3, figsize=(10,4)) 

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
hist.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())   #to get a tick every 1 year
hist.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))     #Show only Year
```

**Output plot**

[image]